# failed to load kubelet config file

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

hy folks

after updating my server, I can't restart kubernetes.

```
Feb  6 10:34:26 chgvas99 kubelet: F0206 10:34:26.662744   27634 server.go:189] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml", error: open /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml: no such file or directory
Feb  6 10:34:26 chgvas99 systemd: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Feb  6 10:34:26 chgvas99 systemd: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Feb  6 10:34:26 chgvas99 systemd: kubelet.service failed.
```

i checked on the directory and indeed there is no **config.yaml** i've the same error on my nodes i cant restart them

server : **3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64**

kubernetes : **Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.3"**
              **GoVersion:"go1.11.5"**

Comment: What about this ? `error: open /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml: no such file or directory`

Comment: i checked if the file config.yaml was here but not !

Comment: by the way the server was setup with **kubeadm**

Comment: You have not specified if "my server" means the master, or a worker node, or whether this machine ever **was** working and mysteriously stopped or what. But, having said that, you might be able to just `rm -rf /etc/kubernetes /var/lib/kubelet` and re-run `kubeadm join ${the_master} --token ${the_token}` and reprovision the node

Comment: thanks for your reply @matthew l Daniel  . the problems happened on all of my k8s ! master and nodes after i've update the os and restart it . i lost the file **config.yaml**

Comment: i dont know how to got back it . can i run on the maste **kubeadm init** to generate the config.yaml or not ? or do i ve to run another command ??

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend runninng 'kubeadm-init' to reinitialise the cluster. Also please make sure you '/var' directory is not full. Please see this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init-phase/) for more information about 'kubeadm init' command.

Answer (score 0):

My Env: 3 master and forefront loadbalancer while initializing cluster

Had to adjust my load balancer and take out other master nodes and "kubeadm init"  and issue was gone , Network error possibly .

Then readd all the other master nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue where got that error on control join command. It ended up being the load balancer ip assigned to the joining control as secondary  from a previous installation (which has nothing running behind it). Run `ip a` and make sure that the joining node does not have secondary load balancer ip.

```sh
echo y | kubeadm reset || true
rm -rf /etc/cni/net.d || true
rm -rf /var/lib/etcd || true
rm -rf ~/.kube || true
ip address delete {{ k8s_apiserver_vip_cidr }} dev {{ k8s_interface }}
kubeadm join ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using [kubeadm](/questions/tagged/kubeadm) - So The fact that `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` is empty is probably related to the worker node not being joined to the cluster.

This might be related to networking issues - but lets try step by step:

1 ) Create a valid token for the worker node to join the cluster:
 Run:  `sudo kubeadm token create --print-join-command --v=5` and make sure you receive an output command like:

```
kubeadm join <master-node-ip>:6443 --token aa334.. --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:..
```

2 ) Run the provided command in the worker node.

3 ) If Everything is OK - the `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` should be populated and the status of `sudo systemctl status kubelet` should look good.

4 ) If you can an error - try running the ame join command with `--v=5` - you'll probably see some networking issues.

4.A ) If you got an error like `dial tcp <master-ip>:6443: connect: no route to host` - make sure that you have a communication between your nodes - run `curl <master-node-ip>:6443` from worker node - you'll probably get the same `no route` error.
Go to the master node and open the `6443 port` (I'll assume you're working on secured private network) and try the connectivity again.

4.B ) If opening port in master succeed and you're able to curl from worker to master you should receive a response from the API server like: `Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server`.

5 ) If `curl` succeed but you're still facing connectivity problems try:

5.A ) Comparing the `.kube/config` files of master and worker nodes - make sure the IP of the API server is correct.

5.B ) Make sure you enabled bridge networking mode on all nodes: `sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1`.

5.C ) Make sure you have an SDN solution like [calico](https://www.projectcalico.org/calico-networking-for-kubernetes/), [flannel](https://coreos.com/flannel/docs/latest/kubernetes.html) or [weave](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/) and that you see that the relevant kube-system pods are running:

```
$kubectl -n kube-system get pods
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-f9fd979d6-lpdlc                   1/1     Running   2          7d12h
coredns-f9fd979d6-vcs7g                   1/1     Running   2          7d12h
etcd-master-node-k8s                      1/1     Running   2          7d12h
kube-apiserver-master-node-k8s            1/1     Running   2          7d12h
kube-controller-manager-master-node-k8s   1/1     Running   2          7d12h
kube-proxy-kh2lc                          1/1     Running   2          7d12h
kube-proxy-lfmc4                          1/1     Running   0          4m36s
kube-scheduler-master-node-k8s            1/1     Running   2          7d12h
weave-net-59r5b                           2/2     Running   6          7d11h <-- Here 
weave-net-c44d6                           2/2     Running   1          4m36s <-- Here
```

6 ) If nothing works - try running `kubeadm reset` on the worker node.